# If element hasClass, add another class to its title value

Tags: this, slick.js, jquery

I'm using slick carousel, and once a div is active I want to open the corresponding description.

Problem I'm having is with this code:

```
if ($('div').hasClass('active')) {
  var title = $(this).attr('title');
  $('ul li').removeClass('open');
  $(title).addClass('open');
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve:
Once a div gets class 'active', I want to take its title value, and use it as a id link to list element I want to display(add class to).

[Here is a FIDDLE.](https://jsfiddle.net/bvrumh83/)

Comment: Use the event `afterChange` of the slick slider to check if the current element has the class `active`, currently you code just runs on page load and not when the class changes

Comment: I'm a beginner, not quite sure how to use that. Also, when I initialize a class in the code itself, list element doesn't change.

Answer (score 2):

Use event handling, not class monitoring.

The slick carousel API has events for this, I believe you want to use the `afterChange` event to act on the active element after it has been made visible.

Check out the docs and examples, especially the section titled "Events" on Slick page: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

And I think you don't want to use `title` attribute for this because that is for tooltips. I recommend `data-*` attributes instead. And element IDs should generally start with a letter and not a number (was required in HTML4 and makes life easier when mapping IDs to JavaScript variables; though if you are using HTML5 I think this requirement is no longer in effect).

HTML

```
<div id="carousel">
<div data-content-id="content1">
  Selector 1 </div>
<div data-content-id="content2">
  Selector 2 </div>
<div data-content-id="content3">
  Selector 3 </div>
</div>
<ul class="content">
  <li id="content1">Content 1</li>
  <li id="content2">Content 2</li>
  <li id="content3">Content 3</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#carousel').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
    // get the associated content id
    var contentId = $(slick.$slides.get(currentSlide)).data("content-id");
    if(contentId && contentId.length)
    {
        var $content = $("#" + contentId);

        $(".content>li").removeClass("open"); // hide other content

        $content.addClass("open"); // show target content, or whatever...
    }
});
```

Comment: This seems to stop my carousel altogether, I can't figure out why
[link] (https://jsfiddle.net/bvrumh83/3/) FIDDLE

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. I forgot to include the `event` parameter in the handler. Fixed code and your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1nmuq1f4/ (Your fiddle didn't define `open` as a class, so i changed it from `li open` to `li.open`)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

```
$('.slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
       var contentId= $(slick.$slides.get(currentSlide)).data('content');
       if(contentId)
       {
            $(".content li").removeClass('open');
            $('#' + contentId).addClass('open');
       }
});
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bvrumh83/5/)

Comment: Be careful when using `.content li` because it will pick up ALL `LI` elements in the content, so if your content contains list items (or somebody else's who uses your code) then it will mess with their style too. This is why I was using `.content>li` instead, but may be better to simply put a `content_item` class on the `LI` elements so you can style them directly

Comment: this is just for the demonstration, in real project i'm using class :)